# What astronauts and/or pilots had their "own" T-38 for transportation and practice?

Tags: nasa, t-38

It appears that the T-38 was used as a means of transportation for certain personnel. Astronauts, and certain pilots? It appears it was also used for training in some cases.

From some articles regarding astronaut training, it seems that some of them had their "own" T-38, that they could more or less use arbitrarily for transportation and training.

I'm curious what pilots and/or astronauts had access to T-38's, and to what degree they had their "own" plane. What were the limitations surrounding their use? Could an astronaut of the Apollo era, take the T-38 for a recreational trip to some other airport?

I'm thinking of articles such as [this](http://astronautrheaseddon.com/may-borrow-jet/):

> Yes, the jets were used for transportation to training sites.

and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-117_Nighthawk)

> After the announcement pilots could fly the F-117 during daytime and no longer needed to be associated with the A-7, flying the T-38 supersonic trainer for travel and training instead.

Answer (score 6):

No pilot or astronaut has "their own aircraft". Not in any unit I've ever seen.
Their name might be painted on the side of one, but they fly whatever the maintenance shop gives them for that day and mission.

Transportation? Sure. "Major Snuffy has to go to Houston for some training on the FooBar hardware. Ralph, take him, and go back on Thursday to pick him up."
Of course, this counts towards flight hours, mission and route planning, etc, etc.

"Borrow" a jet"? When I was stationed at Griffiss AFB NY in the late 70's, we sometimes had a pilot go for a weekend cross country. Leave Thursday or Friday afternoon, come back Sunday afternoon. Off to Frostbite Falls, MN Regional airport, to visit Mummy and Daddy for a couple of days. And we were loading golf clubs, skis, whatever, in the underwing travel pod.

Comment: Having kept my plane at Reno for a good many years, at an FBO that also serviced transient military, I can say that I certainly saw more fighter jets (and sometimes transports like the  C5) on the ramp on weekends than during the week.

Comment: Strategic Air Command had program for copilots to fly T37 trainers so they could get more fly hours at less expense then flying B52s or KC135s. Many pilots would take overnight bag and a set of golf clubs and fly to other SAC bases to visit friends and play a round of golf. We often joked that the golf course was built as soon as the runway was finished at a new base.

Answer (score 3):

[Over the years](https://www.gao.gov/assets/210/202205.pdf) NASA has maintained a fairly sizable fleet of T-38's for use by the astronauts and the T-38 has been widely used by NASA as a training and proficiency aircraft as well as a chase plane. [Astronauts are generally required to log a fair bit of time monthly to stay current.](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/flyout/t38flyout.html)

> Anyone who didn't fly a T-38 before they got to NASA learned to fly it
> once they joined the astronaut corps. Basic astronaut training
> includes T-38 courses, and mission specialists, who do not sit at the
> controls of a space shuttle, have to record four hours a month at the
> stick of a T-38. Commanders and pilots are required to fly the T-38
> for 15 hours a month to keep up their proficiency.

In the early days the jets were used for hopping around the country since the Saturn V was built by many sub-contractors as [was the case of the fatal NASA 901 Flight](https://www.americaspace.com/2016/02/28/50-years-since-the-accident-which-changed-project-gemini-part-2/)

> Over the course of several months of training, See had flown 25 times
> and Bassett seven times to St. Louis, in order to visit the McDonnell
> Aircraft Corp., where their Gemini IX spacecraft was being built. The
> flight from Ellington Field to Lambert Field took approximately 90
> minutes and on the morning of 28 February 1966 See and Bassett,
> together with Stafford and Cernan, were headed to St. Louis for ten
> days of intensive rendezvous training on the Gemini simulator. They
> would also have the opportunity to view their spacecraft as it
> approached completion on the McDonnell production line.

[Its reported that Michael Collins (Apollo 11) flew his T-38 alone often, to "commute" however this was between two NASA facilities](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2019/07/michael-collins-moon-landing-apollo-11/594238/)

> Collins spent months training for the delicate particulars of the
> Apollo 11 mission. He commuted between NASA centers in Houston and
> Cape Canaveral on a T-38, a slinky two-seater jet, usually alone.

But... [In 1994 they got into some trouble](https://www.nytimes.com/1994/04/24/us/audit-says-astronauts-fly-jets-to-resort-sites.html), and it appears they were flying them just to "go places"

> Astronauts at the Johnson Space Center in Houston have flown
> two-seater supersonic jets to Colorado Springs on weekends during ski
> season as well as to New Orleans and Fort Lauderdale, Fla., according
> to NASA's inspector general.
>
> While the astronauts said they were fulfilling the flight time
> required of them each month, some lawmakers criticized the flights to
> resort cities. Each costs about $2,000 an hour.

...[and apparently it happens every once in a while](https://www.nytimes.com/1994/04/24/us/audit-says-astronauts-fly-jets-to-resort-sites.html)

> This is not the first time that astronaut flights on T-38's have been
> criticized. From 1986 to 1990 there were more than 10 incidents
> involving T-38's. In one, in May 1989, a Pan American World Airways
> jetliner reported a "near midair collision" with a T-38 at Dulles
> International Airport in Virginia.

The article goes on to discuss that the flights for proficiency were "loosely" monitored and NASA cared more about them getting their time in than the destination which appears to have lead to some not-so-sanctioned use of the aircraft.

On a bit of a side note this is a fairly common thing in aviation. Since the [FAA required civilians to keep up certain currencies](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/1033391) flight are routinely conducted for the purposes of maintaining currency instead of going somewhere specific, [often pilots will simply fly to get lunch somewhere...](https://www.inquirer.com/philly/food/100-dollar-hamburger-airport-food-pilot-20180612.html)

Answer (score 2):

While stationed at NAS Glenview in 1970, I had Hangar One watch duty late one summer night.  I got a call to park an arriving NASA T-38 on the flight line.  It was Gene Cernan by himself that exited the aircraft.  I walked with him to Flight Operations, all business, no small talk.  He had yet to walk on the moon.  Chicago was his home town and I am sure this was not his only trip.  Buzz Aldrin also showed up there once but I never saw him, only the T-38.  Somebody in the VA-209 squadron spray painted the Blackawk insignia on the landing gear and heard Aldrin was furious, demanding heads to roll.